# Quick way to change empty $_POST data to NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a form with over 50+ fields, with roughly 20 optional fields.

Is there any easy way to process `$_POST` data in one hit to remove empty strings and change them to NULL prior to inserting into the database, or do they have to be done one by one in the following method:

```
if ($_POST['field_x'] == "") {
    $_POST['field_x'] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I sure hope you're escaping that `$_POST` somewhere down the line using PDO or `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Careful, that above code will turn 0 into NULL too. Might be intentional, but an `===` might be better.

Comment: @Johan - I am using PDO, that's what is causing me the issue as it stands at the moment. If I remove the empty strings using array_filter I then lose the $_POST data, thus causing an error when binding the params with PDO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use array_filter:

```
$post = array_filter($_POST);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

To only remove empty strings you can use:

```
function drop_empty($var)
{
  return ($var === '') ? NULL : $var;
}

$post = array_filter($_POST, 'drop_empty');
```

If you don't want to drop values, but only want to set them to NULL: use `array_map`:

```
$post = array_map('drop_empty', $_POST);
```

Comment: Thank you, see my comment below - have a bit of an issue using array_filter

Comment: Use `array_map` instead, with the above function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: I'm sure both ways will come in handy in the future - thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Setting all elements that are an empty string to NULL:

```
foreach ($_POST as &$v) {
    if ($v !== "") {
        continue
    }
    $v = NULL;
}
unset($v); // remove the reference (alias) to the last element of $_POST
```

Answer (score 3):

This is nice and concise, but it will also remove POST values like the integer `0` or anything else that evaluates to false when cast to (bool)

```
$_POST = array_filter($_POST);
```

If that won't work for you you can use a callback function that compares using `===` to `""`

You should also note that this is more like calling `unset()` rather than setting the array element to `NULL`, which is quite similar and probably good enough / even better for your situation.

Comment: I'm current using PDO with prepared statements, if I were to remove the empty string values completely I would receive an error from PDO due to the mismatch is bind params. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @PaulPRO: array_filter doesn't change them to NULL do they?

Comment: @lethal Yes, use `array_map` instead of `array_filter`. Luwe beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : NULL)
```

Easier inline method for PDO binding. isset() is a special function. You can't call another function to then check isset() on a variable.

Example:

```
$conn = new PDO($pdo_connection, $pdo_username, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `t` WHERE `x`=:x');
$stmt->bindValue(':x', (isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : NULL), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer of hakre my solution for this is:

```
foreach ($_POST as &$v) {
  $v = (is_numeric($v) ? $v : ($v === "" ? "NULL" : "'" . $v . "'"));
}
unset($v);
```

So afterwards I concat my SQL command like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $mytable (number, name, description)
             VALUES (" . $_POST['number'] . ","
                       . $_POST['name'] . ","
                       . $_POST['description'] . ")";
```

In fact I got no other method working to really get NULL for all emtpy $_POST variables into the database field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($v) || $v === '') {
        $_POST[$k] = null;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign $_POST['data'] to a variable, like $a=$_POST['data']; after usage of variable $a, make it empty like $a=""; or $a=null;